# View's not updating properly in ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, constraints

I have a ScrollView with two views, when I click more button on "view 1" ---> I'm removing that button and loading big view from .xib. Here the problem is the bottom view "view 2" it is not moving to bottom and ScrollView not scrolling.

[image]

My code is :

```
@IBAction func onClickMoreBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.moreBtn.removeFromSuperview()

        //Load view
        let loadMoreView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SubView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? SubView
        self.view1.addSubview(loadMoreView!)
        self.view1.frame = CGRect(x: self.view1.frame.origin.x, y: self.view1.frame.origin.y, width: self.view1.frame.width, height: 400)
        //Set the frame of the more view to match its superview (the view1)
        loadMoreView?.frame = self.view1.bounds
        // let it resize if needed (such as device rotation)
        loadMoreView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        print(loadMoreView?.frame as Any)


    }

}
```

Comment: Show how you have your constraints set up. Impossible to tell what's going on with only the information you've shown.

Comment: @ DonMag, I added constraints through storyboard and when I increase view 1 height it's scrolling, but the only problem is when I load xib then only view 2 not moving bottom of view1.

Comment: You're setting `loadMoreView`'s frame to `view1.bounds` -- so you can't expect it to change the size of `view1`. If you want it to, you need to set its frame to a different size.

Comment: @ DonMag, here **self.view1** is one subView in VC's view. I want to load my xib file in that view1.

Comment: @DonMag, actually its resizing. But the problem is it's resizing based on tableview content size. Suppose if I have 10 cells it's displaying around 7to 8 only. not all.

Comment: Still... you have `view1`... it has a size (via constraints or intrinsic size)... then you add `loadMoreView` as a subview, but you're setting its size to the existing `view1` size: `loadMoreView?.frame = self.view1.bounds`... so, nothing is going to change. If `loadMoreView` has an intrinsic size (based on its content), then you need to change the frame of `view1` -- or define constraints that will allow it to auto-size based on `loadMoreView`

Comment: *"it's resizing based on tableview content size. Suppose if I have 10 cells it's displaying around 7to 8 only. not all"* --- ok, that's an entirely different problem. You need to update your question with ***all*** of the relevant information.

Comment: Here I added scrollview for my view1.